# How to write the following switch case with less lines of code?

Tags: php

How do I write the following switch case code using less lines? It is taking up a lot of space and lines but I'm unsure what's the better way of writing this.
This is a function where I am calculating the price which I have set in WordPress backend according to the various distance range.
if the distance is less than 300 miles, I have a fixed rate set in the backend for various distance range and if it is greater than 300 miles, then I want to use price per mile. The code does exactly what I need but I feel there can be more compact way of writing this?

Thanks in advance!

Following is the code:

```
function calculatePrice($distance_value_complete, $fixed_rate, $variable_rate) {

    if (floatval($distance_value_complete) < 300 ):

        switch (true) {

            case floatval($distance_value_complete) < 2:
                $vehicle_price1 = $fixed_rate['upto_2_mile'];
                break;

            case ( (floatval($distance_value_complete) >= 2) && (floatval($distance_value_complete) < 4) ):
                $vehicle_price1 = $fixed_rate['from_2_to_4_miles'];
                break;

            case ( (floatval($distance_value_complete) >= 4) && (floatval($distance_value_complete) < 9) ):
                $vehicle_price1 = $fixed_rate['from_4_to_9_miles'];
                break;

            case ( (floatval($distance_value_complete) >= 9) && (floatval($distance_value_complete) < 14) ):
                $vehicle_price1 = $fixed_rate['from_9_to_14_miles'];
                break;

            case ( (floatval($distance_value_complete) >= 14) && (floatval($distance_value_complete) < 19) ):
                $vehicle_price1 = $fixed_rate['from_14_to_19_miles'];
                break;

            case ( (floatval($distance_value_complete) >= 19) && (floatval($distance_value_complete) < 25) ):
            $vehicle_price1 = $fixed_rate['from_19_to_25_miles'];
            break;

            case ( (floatval($distance_value_complete) >= 25) && (floatval($distance_value_complete) < 29) ):
                $vehicle_price1 = $fixed_rate['from_25_to_29_miles'];
                break;

            case ( (floatval($distance_value_complete) >= 29) && (floatval($distance_value_complete) < 35) ):
                $vehicle_price1 = $fixed_rate['from_29_to_35_miles'];
                break;

            case ( (floatval($distance_value_complete) >= 35) && (floatval($distance_value_complete) < 40) ):
                $vehicle_price1 = $fixed_rate['from_35_to_40_miles'];
                break;

            case ( (floatval($distance_value_complete) >= 40) && (floatval($distance_value_complete) < 45) ):
                $vehicle_price1 = $fixed_rate['from_40_to_45_miles'];
                break;

            case ( (floatval($distance_value_complete) >= 45) && (floatval($distance_value_complete) < 50) ):
                $vehicle_price1 = $fixed_rate['from_45_to_50_miles'];
                break;

            case ( (floatval($distance_value_complete) >= 50) && (floatval($distance_value_complete) < 56) ):
                $vehicle_price1 = $fixed_rate['from_50_to_56_miles'];
                break;

            case ( (floatval($distance_value_complete) >= 56) && (floatval($distance_value_complete) < 62) ):
                $vehicle_price1 = $fixed_rate['from_56_to_62_miles'];
                break;

            case ( (floatval($distance_value_complete) >= 62) && (floatval($distance_value_complete) < 70) ):
                $vehicle_price1 = $fixed_rate['from_62_to_70_miles'];
                break;

            case ( (floatval($distance_value_complete) >= 70) && (floatval($distance_value_complete) < 80) ):
                $vehicle_price1 = $fixed_rate['from_70_to_80_miles'];
                break;

            case ( (floatval($distance_value_complete) >= 80) && (floatval($distance_value_complete) < 90) ):
                $vehicle_price1 = $fixed_rate['from_80_to_90_miles'];
                break;

            case ( (floatval($distance_value_complete) >= 90) && (floatval($distance_value_complete) < 100) ):
                $vehicle_price1 = $fixed_rate['from_90_to_100_miles'];
                break;

            case ( (floatval($distance_value_complete) >= 100) && (floatval($distance_value_complete) < 110) ):
                $vehicle_price1 = $fixed_rate['from_100_to_110_miles'];
                break;

            case ( (floatval($distance_value_complete) >= 110) && (floatval($distance_value_complete) < 120) ):
                $vehicle_price1 = $fixed_rate['from_110_to_120_miles'];
                break;

            case ( (floatval($distance_value_complete) >= 120) && (floatval($distance_value_complete) < 130) ):
                $vehicle_price1 = $fixed_rate['from_120_to_130_miles'];
                break;

            case ( (floatval($distance_value_complete) >= 130) && (floatval($distance_value_complete) < 140) ):
                $vehicle_price1 = $fixed_rate['from_130_to_140_miles'];
                break;

            case ( (floatval($distance_value_complete) >= 140) && (floatval($distance_value_complete) < 150) ):
                $vehicle_price1 = $fixed_rate['from_140_to_150_miles'];
                break;

            case ( (floatval($distance_value_complete) >= 150) && (floatval($distance_value_complete) < 160) ):
                $vehicle_price1 = $fixed_rate['from_150_to_160_miles'];
                break;

            case ( (floatval($distance_value_complete) >= 160) && (floatval($distance_value_complete) < 170) ):
                $vehicle_price1 = $fixed_rate['from_160_to_170_miles'];
                break;

            case ( (floatval($distance_value_complete) >= 170) && (floatval($distance_value_complete) < 180) ):
                $vehicle_price1 = $fixed_rate['from_170_to_180_miles'];
                break;

            case ( (floatval($distance_value_complete) >= 180) && (floatval($distance_value_complete) < 190) ):
                $vehicle_price1 = $fixed_rate['from_180_to_190_miles'];
                break;

            case ( (floatval($distance_value_complete) >= 190) && (floatval($distance_value_complete) < 200) ):
                $vehicle_price1 = $fixed_rate['from_190_to_200_miles'];
                break;

            case ( (floatval($distance_value_complete) >= 200) && (floatval($distance_value_complete) < 210) ):
                $vehicle_price1 = $fixed_rate['from_200_to_210_miles'];
                break;

            case ( (floatval($distance_value_complete) >= 210) && (floatval($distance_value_complete) < 220) ):
                $vehicle_price1 = $fixed_rate['from_210_to_220_miles'];
                break;

            case ( (floatval($distance_value_complete) >= 220) && (floatval($distance_value_complete) < 230) ):
                $vehicle_price1 = $fixed_rate['from_220_to_230_miles'];
                break;

            case ( (floatval($distance_value_complete) >= 230) && (floatval($distance_value_complete) < 240) ):
                $vehicle_price1 = $fixed_rate['from_230_to_240_miles'];
                break;

            case ( (floatval($distance_value_complete) >= 240) && (floatval($distance_value_complete) < 250) ):
                $vehicle_price1 = $fixed_rate['from_240_to_250_miles'];
                break;

            case ( (floatval($distance_value_complete) >= 250) && (floatval($distance_value_complete) < 260) ):
                $vehicle_price1 = $fixed_rate['from_250_to_260_miles'];
                break;

            case ( (floatval($distance_value_complete) >= 260) && (floatval($distance_value_complete) < 270) ):
                $vehicle_price1 = $fixed_rate['from_260_to_270_miles'];
                break;

            case ( (floatval($distance_value_complete) >= 270) && (floatval($distance_value_complete) < 280) ):
                $vehicle_price1 = $fixed_rate['from_270_to_280_miles'];
                break;

            case ( (floatval($distance_value_complete) >= 280) && (floatval($distance_value_complete) < 290) ):
                $vehicle_price1 = $fixed_rate['from_280_to_290_miles'];
                break;

            case ( (floatval($distance_value_complete) >= 290) && (floatval($distance_value_complete) < 300) ):
                $vehicle_price1 = $fixed_rate['from_290_to_300_miles'];
                break;
        }

    else:

        switch (true) {

            case floatval($distance_value_complete) >= 300:
                $vehicle_price1 = floatval($distance_value_complete) * $variable_rate['from_300_and_above'];
                break;
        }

    endif;

    return $vehicle_price1;
}
```

Comment: Put it all into a data structure of some kind (like a two-dimensional table or associative array) and use a loop and an `if` statement to identify the desired bracket instead of a switch statement.

Comment: You do realise the number of 'lines' of code you can use is almost limitless. It doesn't really matter. If you don't like looking at it get a code editor with collapse function.

Comment: switch/case in the else path is redundant. You already check "< 300" in the if condition. So, it must be >= 300 if you end up in else branch.

Comment: I'd restructure the array $fixed_rate to have keys [0,2,4,9,....], then write a function to find the next matching key to given $distance_value_complete

Comment: you could do the float val outside of the switch, pass to a variable, and that would save some code and processing for sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply rather not use a `switch` in such cases, where you have to deal with complex comparison expressions:

```
<?php

function calculatePrice($distance_value_complete, $fixed_rate, $variable_rate)
{
    $distance_completed = floatval($distance_value_complete);

    static $minimum_distance = 2;
    static $maximum_distance = 300;

    if ($distance_completed >= $maximum_distance) {
        return $distance_completed * $variable_rate['from_' . $maximum_distance . '_and_above'];;
    }


    if ($distance_completed < $minimum_distance) {
        return $fixed_rate['upto_' . $minimum_distance . '_mile'];
    }

    static $fixed_distances = array(
        4, 9, 14, 19, 25, 29, 35, 40, 45, 50, 56, 62, 70, 80, 90, 100, 
        110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200, 
        210, 220, 230, 240, 250, 260, 270, 280, 290, 300
    );

    $last_distance = $minimum_distance;
    foreach ($fixed_distances as $distance) {
        if ($distance_completed < $distance) {
            return $fixed_rate['from_' . $last_distance . '_to_' . $distance . '_miles'];
        }
        $last_distance = $distance;
    }

    // This should never happen, unless you modify $fixed_distances and forget to change the early return conditions
    throw new \Exception(sprintf('Distance %f out of range', $distance_completed));
}
```

Test results:

````php
0 = upto_2_mile
1 = upto_2_mile
2 = from_2_to_4_miles
3 = from_2_to_4_miles
4 = from_4_to_9_miles
5 = from_4_to_9_miles
6 = from_4_to_9_miles
7 = from_4_to_9_miles
8 = from_4_to_9_miles
9 = from_9_to_14_miles
10 = from_9_to_14_miles
11 = from_9_to_14_miles
12 = from_9_to_14_miles
13 = from_9_to_14_miles
14 = from_14_to_19_miles
15 = from_14_to_19_miles
16 = from_14_to_19_miles
17 = from_14_to_19_miles
18 = from_14_to_19_miles
19 = from_19_to_25_miles
20 = from_19_to_25_miles
21 = from_19_to_25_miles
22 = from_19_to_25_miles
23 = from_19_to_25_miles
24 = from_19_to_25_miles
25 = from_25_to_29_miles
26 = from_25_to_29_miles
27 = from_25_to_29_miles
28 = from_25_to_29_miles
29 = from_29_to_35_miles
30 = from_29_to_35_miles
31 = from_29_to_35_miles
32 = from_29_to_35_miles
33 = from_29_to_35_miles
34 = from_29_to_35_miles
35 = from_35_to_40_miles
36 = from_35_to_40_miles
37 = from_35_to_40_miles
38 = from_35_to_40_miles
39 = from_35_to_40_miles
40 = from_40_to_45_miles
41 = from_40_to_45_miles
42 = from_40_to_45_miles
43 = from_40_to_45_miles
44 = from_40_to_45_miles
45 = from_45_to_50_miles
46 = from_45_to_50_miles
47 = from_45_to_50_miles
48 = from_45_to_50_miles
49 = from_45_to_50_miles
50 = from_50_to_56_miles
51 = from_50_to_56_miles
52 = from_50_to_56_miles
53 = from_50_to_56_miles
54 = from_50_to_56_miles
55 = from_50_to_56_miles
56 = from_56_to_62_miles
57 = from_56_to_62_miles
58 = from_56_to_62_miles
59 = from_56_to_62_miles
60 = from_56_to_62_miles
61 = from_56_to_62_miles
62 = from_62_to_70_miles
63 = from_62_to_70_miles
64 = from_62_to_70_miles
65 = from_62_to_70_miles
66 = from_62_to_70_miles
67 = from_62_to_70_miles
68 = from_62_to_70_miles
69 = from_62_to_70_miles
70 = from_70_to_80_miles
71 = from_70_to_80_miles
72 = from_70_to_80_miles
73 = from_70_to_80_miles
74 = from_70_to_80_miles
75 = from_70_to_80_miles
76 = from_70_to_80_miles
77 = from_70_to_80_miles
78 = from_70_to_80_miles
79 = from_70_to_80_miles
80 = from_80_to_90_miles
81 = from_80_to_90_miles
82 = from_80_to_90_miles
83 = from_80_to_90_miles
84 = from_80_to_90_miles
85 = from_80_to_90_miles
86 = from_80_to_90_miles
87 = from_80_to_90_miles
88 = from_80_to_90_miles
89 = from_80_to_90_miles
90 = from_90_to_100_miles
91 = from_90_to_100_miles
92 = from_90_to_100_miles
93 = from_90_to_100_miles
94 = from_90_to_100_miles
95 = from_90_to_100_miles
96 = from_90_to_100_miles
97 = from_90_to_100_miles
98 = from_90_to_100_miles
99 = from_90_to_100_miles
100 = from_100_to_110_miles
101 = from_100_to_110_miles
102 = from_100_to_110_miles
103 = from_100_to_110_miles
104 = from_100_to_110_miles
105 = from_100_to_110_miles
106 = from_100_to_110_miles
107 = from_100_to_110_miles
108 = from_100_to_110_miles
109 = from_100_to_110_miles
110 = from_110_to_120_miles
111 = from_110_to_120_miles
112 = from_110_to_120_miles
113 = from_110_to_120_miles
114 = from_110_to_120_miles
115 = from_110_to_120_miles
116 = from_110_to_120_miles
117 = from_110_to_120_miles
118 = from_110_to_120_miles
119 = from_110_to_120_miles
120 = from_120_to_130_miles
121 = from_120_to_130_miles
122 = from_120_to_130_miles
123 = from_120_to_130_miles
124 = from_120_to_130_miles
125 = from_120_to_130_miles
126 = from_120_to_130_miles
127 = from_120_to_130_miles
128 = from_120_to_130_miles
129 = from_120_to_130_miles
130 = from_130_to_140_miles
131 = from_130_to_140_miles
132 = from_130_to_140_miles
133 = from_130_to_140_miles
134 = from_130_to_140_miles
135 = from_130_to_140_miles
136 = from_130_to_140_miles
137 = from_130_to_140_miles
138 = from_130_to_140_miles
139 = from_130_to_140_miles
140 = from_140_to_150_miles
141 = from_140_to_150_miles
142 = from_140_to_150_miles
143 = from_140_to_150_miles
144 = from_140_to_150_miles
145 = from_140_to_150_miles
146 = from_140_to_150_miles
147 = from_140_to_150_miles
148 = from_140_to_150_miles
149 = from_140_to_150_miles
150 = from_150_to_160_miles
151 = from_150_to_160_miles
152 = from_150_to_160_miles
153 = from_150_to_160_miles
154 = from_150_to_160_miles
155 = from_150_to_160_miles
156 = from_150_to_160_miles
157 = from_150_to_160_miles
158 = from_150_to_160_miles
159 = from_150_to_160_miles
160 = from_160_to_170_miles
161 = from_160_to_170_miles
162 = from_160_to_170_miles
163 = from_160_to_170_miles
164 = from_160_to_170_miles
165 = from_160_to_170_miles
166 = from_160_to_170_miles
167 = from_160_to_170_miles
168 = from_160_to_170_miles
169 = from_160_to_170_miles
170 = from_170_to_180_miles
171 = from_170_to_180_miles
172 = from_170_to_180_miles
173 = from_170_to_180_miles
174 = from_170_to_180_miles
175 = from_170_to_180_miles
176 = from_170_to_180_miles
177 = from_170_to_180_miles
178 = from_170_to_180_miles
179 = from_170_to_180_miles
180 = from_180_to_190_miles
181 = from_180_to_190_miles
182 = from_180_to_190_miles
183 = from_180_to_190_miles
184 = from_180_to_190_miles
185 = from_180_to_190_miles
186 = from_180_to_190_miles
187 = from_180_to_190_miles
188 = from_180_to_190_miles
189 = from_180_to_190_miles
190 = from_190_to_200_miles
191 = from_190_to_200_miles
192 = from_190_to_200_miles
193 = from_190_to_200_miles
194 = from_190_to_200_miles
195 = from_190_to_200_miles
196 = from_190_to_200_miles
197 = from_190_to_200_miles
198 = from_190_to_200_miles
199 = from_190_to_200_miles
200 = from_200_to_210_miles
201 = from_200_to_210_miles
202 = from_200_to_210_miles
203 = from_200_to_210_miles
204 = from_200_to_210_miles
205 = from_200_to_210_miles
206 = from_200_to_210_miles
207 = from_200_to_210_miles
208 = from_200_to_210_miles
209 = from_200_to_210_miles
210 = from_210_to_220_miles
211 = from_210_to_220_miles
212 = from_210_to_220_miles
213 = from_210_to_220_miles
214 = from_210_to_220_miles
215 = from_210_to_220_miles
216 = from_210_to_220_miles
217 = from_210_to_220_miles
218 = from_210_to_220_miles
219 = from_210_to_220_miles
220 = from_220_to_230_miles
221 = from_220_to_230_miles
222 = from_220_to_230_miles
223 = from_220_to_230_miles
224 = from_220_to_230_miles
225 = from_220_to_230_miles
226 = from_220_to_230_miles
227 = from_220_to_230_miles
228 = from_220_to_230_miles
229 = from_220_to_230_miles
230 = from_230_to_240_miles
231 = from_230_to_240_miles
232 = from_230_to_240_miles
233 = from_230_to_240_miles
234 = from_230_to_240_miles
235 = from_230_to_240_miles
236 = from_230_to_240_miles
237 = from_230_to_240_miles
238 = from_230_to_240_miles
239 = from_230_to_240_miles
240 = from_240_to_250_miles
241 = from_240_to_250_miles
242 = from_240_to_250_miles
243 = from_240_to_250_miles
244 = from_240_to_250_miles
245 = from_240_to_250_miles
246 = from_240_to_250_miles
247 = from_240_to_250_miles
248 = from_240_to_250_miles
249 = from_240_to_250_miles
250 = from_250_to_260_miles
251 = from_250_to_260_miles
252 = from_250_to_260_miles
253 = from_250_to_260_miles
254 = from_250_to_260_miles
255 = from_250_to_260_miles
256 = from_250_to_260_miles
257 = from_250_to_260_miles
258 = from_250_to_260_miles
259 = from_250_to_260_miles
260 = from_260_to_270_miles
261 = from_260_to_270_miles
262 = from_260_to_270_miles
263 = from_260_to_270_miles
264 = from_260_to_270_miles
265 = from_260_to_270_miles
266 = from_260_to_270_miles
267 = from_260_to_270_miles
268 = from_260_to_270_miles
269 = from_260_to_270_miles
270 = from_270_to_280_miles
271 = from_270_to_280_miles
272 = from_270_to_280_miles
273 = from_270_to_280_miles
274 = from_270_to_280_miles
275 = from_270_to_280_miles
276 = from_270_to_280_miles
277 = from_270_to_280_miles
278 = from_270_to_280_miles
279 = from_270_to_280_miles
280 = from_280_to_290_miles
281 = from_280_to_290_miles
282 = from_280_to_290_miles
283 = from_280_to_290_miles
284 = from_280_to_290_miles
285 = from_280_to_290_miles
286 = from_280_to_290_miles
287 = from_280_to_290_miles
288 = from_280_to_290_miles
289 = from_280_to_290_miles
290 = from_290_to_300_miles
291 = from_290_to_300_miles
292 = from_290_to_300_miles
293 = from_290_to_300_miles
294 = from_290_to_300_miles
295 = from_290_to_300_miles
296 = from_290_to_300_miles
297 = from_290_to_300_miles
298 = from_290_to_300_miles
299 = from_290_to_300_miles
300 = from_300_and_above
301 = from_300_and_above
302 = from_300_and_above
303 = from_300_and_above
304 = from_300_and_above
305 = from_300_and_above
306 = from_300_and_above
307 = from_300_and_above
308 = from_300_and_above
309 = from_300_and_above
310 = from_300_and_above
311 = from_300_and_above
312 = from_300_and_above
313 = from_300_and_above
314 = from_300_and_above
315 = from_300_and_above
316 = from_300_and_above
317 = from_300_and_above
318 = from_300_and_above
319 = from_300_and_above
320 = from_300_and_above
321 = from_300_and_above
322 = from_300_and_above
323 = from_300_and_above
324 = from_300_and_above
325 = from_300_and_above
326 = from_300_and_above
327 = from_300_and_above
328 = from_300_and_above
329 = from_300_and_above
330 = from_300_and_above
331 = from_300_and_above
332 = from_300_and_above
333 = from_300_and_above
334 = from_300_and_above
335 = from_300_and_above
336 = from_300_and_above
337 = from_300_and_above
338 = from_300_and_above
339 = from_300_and_above
340 = from_300_and_above
341 = from_300_and_above
342 = from_300_and_above
343 = from_300_and_above
344 = from_300_and_above
345 = from_300_and_above
346 = from_300_and_above
347 = from_300_and_above
348 = from_300_and_above
349 = from_300_and_above
350 = from_300_and_above```
````

Comment: Thank you so much @Sven Mich :) That code worked fine and seems cleaner than my code, thanks again !!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a rate name depending on a single int value I would create an array that maps all the available rates, then pass it to a function with the value you are checking, something like this ( map is not complete, php7.2 required )

```
$conditionMap = [
    [
        'value' => 'upto_2_mile',
        'condition' => '<2'
    ],
    [
        'value' => 'from_2_to_4_miles',
        'condition' => '<4'
    ],
    [
        'value' => 'from_4_to_9_miles',
        'condition' => '<9'
    ],
    [
        'value' => 'from_9_to_14_miles',
        'condition' => '<14'
    ],
    [
        'value' => 'from_14_to_19_miles',
        'condition' => '<19'
    ],
    [
        'value' => 'from_19_to_25_miles',
        'condition' => '<25'
    ],
    [
        'value' => 'from_25_to_29_miles',
        'condition' => '<29'
    ]
];

function getRate(int $value, array $conditionMap) : string {
    $rate = 'Not found';
    foreach ($conditionMap as $condition) {
        $phpString = sprintf("return %s %s;", $value, $condition['condition']);
        $evaluation = eval($phpString);
        if($evaluation) {
            $rate = $condition['value'];
            break;
        }
    }

    return $rate;
}

// TEST
for($i = 0; $i<=30; $i++) {
    var_dump(sprintf("With value %s: %s", $i, getRate($i, $conditionMap)));
}
```

If you run this script you should obtain the result below

```
string(25) "With value 0: upto_2_mile"
string(25) "With value 1: upto_2_mile"
string(31) "With value 2: from_2_to_4_miles"
string(31) "With value 3: from_2_to_4_miles"
string(31) "With value 4: from_4_to_9_miles"
string(31) "With value 5: from_4_to_9_miles"
string(31) "With value 6: from_4_to_9_miles"
string(31) "With value 7: from_4_to_9_miles"
string(31) "With value 8: from_4_to_9_miles"
string(32) "With value 9: from_9_to_14_miles"
string(33) "With value 10: from_9_to_14_miles"
string(33) "With value 11: from_9_to_14_miles"
string(33) "With value 12: from_9_to_14_miles"
string(33) "With value 13: from_9_to_14_miles"
string(34) "With value 14: from_14_to_19_miles"
string(34) "With value 15: from_14_to_19_miles"
string(34) "With value 16: from_14_to_19_miles"
string(34) "With value 17: from_14_to_19_miles"
string(34) "With value 18: from_14_to_19_miles"
string(34) "With value 19: from_19_to_25_miles"
string(34) "With value 20: from_19_to_25_miles"
string(34) "With value 21: from_19_to_25_miles"
string(34) "With value 22: from_19_to_25_miles"
string(34) "With value 23: from_19_to_25_miles"
string(34) "With value 24: from_19_to_25_miles"
string(34) "With value 25: from_25_to_29_miles"
string(34) "With value 26: from_25_to_29_miles"
string(34) "With value 27: from_25_to_29_miles"
string(34) "With value 28: from_25_to_29_miles"
string(24) "With value 29: Not found"
string(24) "With value 30: Not found"
```